# Tigervnc displays a blank screen

Tags: fedora, vncviewer

0

I have configured tigervnc-server on a Fedora Workstation and when I connect to it via either VNC Viewer from macOS, or vncviewer from another Fedora workstation, all I get is a blank screen, and sometimes a mouse pointer that does not move.

I have looked on a bunch of forums and this seems like a common problem, but all the info is quite old and not current with the latest way tigervnc-server is configured with systemd and gdm.

In this particular instance I have elected to install tigervnc-server using user's service manager (the RHEL8 process https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4201371)) - so it is running in user space.

~/.vnc/xstartup contains:

```
#!/bin/sh

unset SESSION_MANAGER 
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS 
exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
```

~/.vnc/.log
cat log2.log

```
Xvnc TigerVNC 1.10.0 - built Jan 13 2019 00:00:00
Copyright (C) 1999-2019 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.rst)
See https://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.
Underlying X server release 12006000, The X.Org Foundation


Sun Apr  5 13:15:01 2020
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on all interface(s), port 5902
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0

Sun Apr  5 13:15:47 2020
 Connections: accepted: 10.10.10.9::48246
 SConnection: Client needs protocol version 3.8
 SConnection: Client requests security type VeNCrypt(19)
 SVeNCrypt:   Client requests security type TLSVnc (258)

Sun Apr  5 13:15:51 2020
 VNCSConnST:  Server default pixel format depth 24 (32bpp) little-endian rgb888

Sun Apr  5 13:16:03 2020
 VNCSConnST:  closing 10.10.10.9::48246: Clean disconnection
 EncodeManager: Framebuffer updates: 9
 EncodeManager:   Tight:
 EncodeManager:     Solid: 14 rects, 1.53762 Mpixels
 EncodeManager:            224 B (1:27458.2 ratio)
 EncodeManager:     Indexed RLE: 1 rects, 1 kpixels
 EncodeManager:                  394 B (1:10.1827 ratio)
 EncodeManager:   Tight (JPEG):
 EncodeManager:     Full Colour: 14 rects, 96.816 kpixels
 EncodeManager:                  60.25 KiB (1:6.27969 ratio)
 EncodeManager:   Total: 29 rects, 1.63543 Mpixels
 EncodeManager:          60.8535 KiB (1:104.986 ratio)
 TLS:         TLS session wasn't terminated gracefully
 TcpSocket:   unable to get peer name for socket
 Connections: closed: ::0
 ComparingUpdateTracker: 836.526 kpixels in / 800.094 kpixels out
 ComparingUpdateTracker: (1:1.04553 ratio)

Sun Apr  5 13:16:26 2020
 Connections: accepted: 10.10.10.9::48248
 SConnection: Client needs protocol version 3.8
 SConnection: Client requests security type VeNCrypt(19)
 SVeNCrypt:   Client requests security type TLSVnc (258)

Sun Apr  5 13:16:28 2020
 VNCSConnST:  Server default pixel format depth 24 (32bpp) little-endian rgb888

Sun Apr  5 13:16:29 2020
 ComparingUpdateTracker: 0 pixels in / 0 pixels out
 ComparingUpdateTracker: (1:-nan ratio)

Sun Apr  5 13:16:36 2020
 VNCSConnST:  closing 10.10.10.9::48248: Clean disconnection
 EncodeManager: Framebuffer updates: 3
 EncodeManager:   Tight:
 EncodeManager:     Solid: 2 rects, 1.50733 Mpixels
 EncodeManager:            32 B (1:188417 ratio)
 EncodeManager:   Total: 2 rects, 1.50733 Mpixels
 EncodeManager:          32 B (1:188417 ratio)
 TLS:         TLS session wasn't terminated gracefully
 TcpSocket:   unable to get peer name for socket
 Connections: closed: ::0
 ComparingUpdateTracker: 0 pixels in / 0 pixels out
 ComparingUpdateTracker: (1:-nan ratio)
```

The log file captures two attempts to connect straight after a reboot. The first always fails with an "Oops" message even before prompted for the password. The second displays the blank screen.

> Socket:   unable to get peer name for socket

This message made me think it was a firewall problem so I have also tried this with firewalld disabled and stopped - but no luck.

I am sure this is related to gdm - but this is an area I am weak in so looking for suggestions. Thanks